# Unable to deploy Rails app to Heroku Postgres DB using Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rubymine, heroku-postgres

I am using Rubymine to connect to an Heroku hosted Postgres DB.

I was able to connect a few weeks ago, but now I am getting this error whenever I try to connect:

'The specified user/password combination is rejected:
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "X3v...'

My Heroku DB URL is:

```
postgres://<password>:X3vuEswiMHjkADaeI5RQvY4WI4@ec2-23-21-170-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/de8u1hq5ipli85
```

I am using JDBC to connect. In the "Data Source Properties" dialog box the (partial) URL is:

```
jdbc:postgresql://ec2-23-21-170-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/
```

And I have added my username and password to the User and Password fields.

In the advanced tab I have added

```
ssl = true
sslfactory = org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

I'm not sure what I have missed.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is not a solution, but it's works for me:

1. Take away the current connections to databases.
2. Driver Rollback and its settings to default.
3. `sudo service postgresql restart`
4. Now again connect.

I guess, but not sure, system uses same driver for the various editors (*Idea*, *DataGrip*, *pgadmin3*). It's setting a bottleneck.

If you have better solution, please write it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant, but you misinterpreted URL

In URL schema first gous user, then password
`<protocol>://[<user>[:<password]@]<host>[:<port>]/...`
so you mixed username with password